# Where can I find responses in fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

I installed fiddler2 and trying to use it.

Whenever I point on a line, I only see the contents of the request, but not the response (looking at the "raw" tab). Where can I find the responses?

Answer (score 16):

In Fiddler, select the **Inspectors** tab to see the Request and Response. Now, this tab is split horizontally; the **Request Inspectors** are across the top, and the **Response Inspectors** are across the bottom. If you don't see the tabs along the bottom, grab the blue splitter line near the bottom and drag it upward. If you don't see even that, restart Fiddler while holding the **SHIFT** key to reset the UI to its default layout.

Comment: I had to resize some panes before I could see the repsonse